# Receive full/complete serial data via Python

Tags: python, serial-port

I am a newie in Python and hope to get your assistance. I am using Python v2.7 on Windows 8 system.

- Question
  I am trying to talk to robot via serial port by sending some commands, however, I cannot receive COMPLETE results after sending some commands (the commands are with a full/long result), unless I setup the size of result before compiling.

For example,
Here is my code:

```
import ser

ser = serial.Serial(3) # Open COM4

ser.write ('getver  \n')   # Send "get version"command to robot, this     cmd is with a long result

print ser.read(1299)  # 1299 is the response size, I get the response previously via terminal, that is why I know how large it is
```

Concern

I believe it is not efficient to count 'how many bytes are there in result' and set it up before compiling.

Is there a way that Python can automatically sense how large the response would be and receive the full/complete response from robot?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do *you* know that the response is complete? Implement that and repeat reading until the message's end is reached.

Comment: Hi Hanno, the way I know if the response is complete or not is by sending same command to terminal (I am using TeraTerm). From the terminal, I can get the full return and then I can compare it with the result I get via Python.

Comment: Sure. But how do you see that the response is complete? Is it terminated by a newline, or is it complete when no more data arrives within 10 seconds, or something else? There must be some means to determine the end of the message.

Comment: Hi Hanno, that is a good question. In my knowledge, if the response is got by terminal, then it is complete. By the way, the format of return is a list  line by line, like this (I omit some because it is too long...): Line 1, Component,Major,Minor,Build,Aux  Line 2, APPassword,2F666439 Line 3, BaseID,0.0,0.0,0,0, Line 4, BatteryType,4,LIION_4CELL_SMART,

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904322/read-full-serial-data-in-python

Comment: yes...that is also what I posted, but have not got the answer yet... =(